# how to read a parameter from json file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, readfile

for the beginning my json file contain the following code only:

```
{
  "url": "https://www.sport5.co.il"
}
```

I want to read 'url' parameter in my code in js.

THANKS !

Comment: first load the file by ajax, and must run it under web-application or web-server

Comment: Get data from file and set it to a variable, for example in data and get it by using data.url or by data['url'] and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

first get file using `$http` from angularJs and then use

```
$scope.url = "";
var mainInfo = null;
$http.get('url of your file').success(function(data) {
    mainInfo = data;
    $scope.url = mainInfo.url;
    alert("$scope.url");
});
```

Comment: first, thanks all for all the help .
second @AmeyaDeshpande, how can i extract the url outside this scope ? i am trying and it's undefined.

Comment: @TomCohen see the edit. attach it to $scope and you will get it throughout the controller and in view also

Answer (score -2):

You can use jquery to achieve this.

```js
$.getJSON(
  "https://api.myjson.com/bins/jdahh",
  function(data) {

    // Success! Do stuff with data.
    alert(data.url);

  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```